# Calling SKIP() in code or using TOP in function

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-6

I'm coding an application with Entity Framework in which I rely heavily on user defined functions.

I have a question about the best way (most optimized way) of how I limit and page my result sets. Basically I am wondering if these two options are the same or one is prefered performance wise.

Option 1.

```
//C#
var result1 = _DB.fn_GetData().OrderBy(x => Id).Skip(page *100).Take(100).ToList();

// SQL in fn_GetData
SELECT * FROM [Data].[Table]
```

Option 2.

```
//C#
var result2 = _DB.fn_GetData(page = 0, size = 100).ToList();

// SQL in fn_GetData
SELECT * FROM [Data].[Table]
ORDER BY Id
OFFSET (size * page) ROWS FETCH NEXT size ROWS ONLY
```

To me these seem to be producing about the same result, but maybe I am missing some key aspect.

Comment: What do you think? Pulling all data into memory vs only 100 rows?

Comment: As @GertArnold hints at, Option 2 will perform better and allows composition of additional clauses. Over-eager application of `ToList` is really annoying.

Comment: The DBMS will be able to optimize / cache / whatever all of this _much_ more efficiently than you ever could in code. Plus: Less transmission load ...

Comment: BTW: Why didn't you just hack together a little benchmark for both to let the numbers speak?

Comment: But is it really pulling them all in to memory, or is it optimizing it as the query is sent to the SQL. Since I am not doing .ToList() untill at the very end the entire SQL query should go to the database.

Comment: IIRC, since SQL Server 2012, Linq to SQL will translate `.Skip().Take()` into an `OFFSET ... FETCH` query. I haven't got immediate access to check this right now, but might be worth doing yourself using Profiler.

Comment: Just enable logging sql queries to console, run both and see what SQL is sent to database, then choose the best.

Comment: @Diado this is the result that I saw too, it did not pull all the data. Butt maybe there is something else I am missing.

Comment: So now it has become quite unclear what you mean by *SQL in fn_GetData*. If it's not the SQL that's executed by the database then what is it? It's quite relevant to know what happens in `fn_GetData`.

Comment: Additionally, you should replace `*` with an explicit column list to prevent future headaches when your schema changes.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to be aware when your LINQ statement is `AsEnumerable` and when it is `AsQueryable`. As long as your statement is an `IQueryable<...>` the software will try to translate it into SQL and let your database do the query. Once it really has lost the `IQueryable`, and has become an implementation of an `IEnumerable`, the data has been brought to local memory, and all further LINQ statements will be performed by your process, not by the database.

If you use your debugger, you will see that the return value of your `fn_getData` returns an IEnumerable. This means that the result of `fn_GetData` is brought to local memory and your OrderBy etc is performed by your process.

Usually it is much more efficient to only move the records that you will use to local memory. Besides: do not fetch the complete records, but only the properties that you plan to use. So in this case I guess you'll have to create an extended version of `fn_GetData` that returns only the values you plan to use

Answer (score 0):

I suggest second option because SQL Server can more faster then C# methods.

In your first option, you take all of the records in table and loop through. But second option, SQL Server do it for you and you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the limiting and where clauses (it depends on table indexes) in the database as far as possible. For first example;

```
var result1 = _DB.fn_GetData().OrderBy(x => Id).Skip(page *100).Take(100).ToList();

// SQL in fn_GetData
SELECT * FROM [Data].[Table]
```

The whole table is retrieved from database into in-memory and it kills the performance and reliability. I strongly don't suggest it. You should consider to put some limitations to filter records on the database. So, the second option is better approach in this case.